# ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) [Errno 60] Operation timed out

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud

I am facing this issue with my macbook how can I solve this. I have good internet connection with 100MB/s

```
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) [Errno 60] Operation timed out
This may be due to network connectivity issues. Please check your network settings, and the status of the service you are trying to reach
```

Comment: Try appending `--log-http` to the command to log the underlying calls. Perhaps `--verbosity=debug` too.

Answer (score 0):

Would like to extend what DazWilkin said, there is a flag `--log-http` to print the

http request/response logs for gcloud.

Try running the following command:

> gcloud container clusters get-credentials Name --region REGION --project projectid --log-http

> gcloud container clusters list --log-http

Also,try in the Cloud Shell from the GCP console.